# Node js client isn’t connecting to server running on 127.0.0.1:8080

Tags: node.js, tcp, server, client

I’m trying to create a Node js TCP server and client. Currently I’m running the server on the IP address of 127.0.0.1:8080.
And my client is trying to connect to that IP. I have no idea as to why this is failing, Here is my code:

```
var net = require('net');
const readline = require('readline');

var clients = [];

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

function OpenServer() {
  var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.write('Echo server\n');
    socket.name = socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort;
    socket.write(socket.name + " joined the chat\n");

    socket.on('data', function(data) {
      socket.write('socket Received: ' + data + '\n');
    });

    socket.on('connect', function(data){
      socket.write("new connection");
    });

    socket.pipe(socket);
  }).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
}

function OpenClient() {
  var client = new net.Socket();
  client.connect(8080, "127.0.0.1", function() {
    console.log('Connected');
  });

  client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Client Received: ' + data + '\n');
    rl.question('How are you today? ', (answer) => {
      // TODO: Log the answer in a database
      client.write(`Thank you ${answer}`);
      rl.close();
    });
  });
  client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
  });
}
OpenClient(); OpenServer();
```

Here is the error I get when i run the client.

> Process crashed with: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080 
>   at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1174:14)

I’d also like to say, I kind of don’t really know what the IP 127.0.0.1 is.
If anyone has a better solution or better way of doing this, I’m very open to here it.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the localhost. How do you run the script?

Comment: I run it using the command line (I run it on windows 10) and sometimes Repl.it

Comment: Open the server _before_ opening the client, that is, do `OpenServer()` then `OpenClient()`

Comment: I just tried that, I got that error again, i even put the OpenClient(); in the OpenServer() function

Comment: @RidleyNelson your example works fine on my machine. Try using another port.

Comment: Sorry, I know this is not following Stack Overflow’s rules, but can I use a url for the host instead of on IP address?